# The type or namespace name 'EventInstanceName' does not exist in the namespace 'SomeNamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the error in the title.
I have made sure that I am building both the projects in x86, and  .net framework4, Active (Any CPU), Active (Debug).

Also the property Copy local is True for the referenced project. The referenced project builds.

I am trying to reference, an instance of the event. For example, see below code.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
public partial class SomeClass : UserControl
{
public ABCEventsHelper AbcEvent = new ABCEventsHelper ();
}
}
```

Above code is compiled as a class library and used in some other project in the same solution. A call like below throws above error.

```
 namespace ConsumeEvents
    {
    public partial class AppForm : Form
    {
    private void AppForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

private void ABCEventsHandler (object oEvent)
{
switch (choice)
{
case SomeNamespace.AbcEvent:
{

}
}
}
    }

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is the reference an assembly reference or project reference? I would remove the reference and try re-adding it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Its a project reference. I tried readding it without success.

Comment: The only other thing I would suggest is make sure the .NET versions they are compiled against are the same. This has happened to me when building against third party libraries.. they are built using .NET 4 when my client used .NET 2 and it couldn't find anything inside the assembly.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead. I made sure that the versions match. They are all built in .net4 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SomeNamespace.AbcEvent` is not a type or value.  `SomeNamespace.SomeClass` has an event named `AbcEvent`, but it's not static so you can't reference it statically, and it's unclear how you're trying to use it in a `switch` statement.

Comment: @D Stanley Is there any way to reference that event?

Comment: @user2951819 You'd need an instance of `SomeClass` to get to it's event handlers.  What is `choice` supposed to be?

Comment: @D Stanley choice would be an event.

Comment: @user2951819 an event is a class member and can't be passed around as if it were a value.  Perhaps if you explained more what you're trying to accomplish a better solution would be presented.